# How to change numerically continuous file names into same prefix but different suffix names?

Tags: linux, sed, awk

Suppose I have 4000 files:

```
output1
output2
output3
output4
output5
output6
output7
output8 
.....
output3999
output4000
```

How can I change every two numerically continuous files with the same prefix but different suffix? In the example I want the file names to be changed into:

```
output1        -> Type0001_A.abc
output2        -> Type0001_B.abc
output3        -> Type0002_A.abc
output4        -> Type0002_B.abc
output5        -> Type0003_A.abc
output6        -> Type0003_B.abc
output7        -> Type0004_A.abc
output8        -> Type0004_B.abc
.....             .....
output3999     -> Type2000_A.abc
output4000     -> Type2000_B.abc
```

I've done a simple loop that can solve the prefix, but got no idea how the suffix numbers and letters can be done.

```
for i in `find . -name "output*"`
do
l=`echo $i |sed 's/output/Type/'`
'$i > $l`
done
```

Any suggestions? Further online references about "loops" are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: You could easily do this in a for loop that increases by 2, but that doesn't allow for any sanity checks.

Comment: I suggest using a scripting language of your choice to generate a series of `mv` commands that you can inspect visually before feeding them into a shell. Should be a matter of one loop and some simple arithmetic / string manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write:

```
for suffix in 000{1..9} 00{10..99} 0{100..999} {1000..2000} ; do
    mv "output$((10#$suffix * 2 - 1))" "Type${suffix}_A.abc"
    mv "output$((10#$suffix * 2))" "Type${suffix}_B.abc"
done
```

Notes:

- The double-quotes aren't needed here, but without them, the Stack Overflow syntax highlighter gets very confused. (In particular, it thinks the `#` in the base-ten-arithmetic-constant starts a comment.) And hey, it's always good practice to wrap parameter-expansions in double-quotes, anyway.
- If you want, you could simplify the first line a bit by using the external program `seq`, and writing `$(seq -w 1 2000)` instead of `000{1..9} 00{10..99} 0{100..999} {1000..2000}`. For that matter, if you have Bash 4.x, you can just write `{0001..2000}`.

Comment: Very nice. Can you clarify what the `10#` does? Is it just substring removal?

Comment: @N13: Inside an arithmetic expression, a constant of the form `7#32` means "the integer that, in base `7`, is expressed as `32`" (i.e., 3×7+2=23). Usually `10#` isn't necessary, but a constant that starts with `0` is taken to be in base 8 -- for example, `032` means 3×8+2=26 -- and `$suffix` was zero-padded to four digits, so I used the prefix `10#` to prevent that.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed & parallel):

```
parallel --xapply mv output{1} Type{2}.abc ::: $(seq 4000) ::: $(seq -f '%04g_A' 2000|sed 'h;s/A/B/;H;g')
```

Answer (score 1):

with bash:

```
i=0
ab=( [0]=A [1]=B )
for f in output*; do 
    n=${f#output}
    printf -v newname "Type%04d_%c.abc\n" $(( (n+1)/2 )) ${ab[i]}
    i=$(( (i+1)%2 ))
    mv "$f" "$newname"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
seq 1 2000 | while read num; do
  echo "output$((num*2-1))" "Type$(printf "%04d" $num)_A.abc"
  echo "output$((num*2+0))" "Type$(printf "%04d" $num)_B.abc"
done
```

If you are happy with the output, change `echo` by `mv`.

References on loop can be found in your shell's man.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with awk:

```
awk '{if(NR%2){printf "%s%s%04d%s\n",$0, " -> Type",(NR+1)/2,"_A.abc"} else {printf "%s%s%04d%s\n",$0, " -> Type",NR/2,"_B.abc" }}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel you can do this:

```
parallel mv output{#} Type{1}_{2}.abc ::: {0001..2000} ::: A B
```